# Solving linear system to find weights in $[0,1]$

Tags: linear-algebra, svd, python

Premise: the implementation will be done in Python.

I have a number of points being tracked in space ($x$, $y$ and $z$ for each frame). I also have a set of pre-defined movements $S$ (from $1$ to $n$) that affect all of the points being tracked (from $1$ to $m$). What I am trying to do is to build a linear system of the form

[image] [image]

All of the terms $S$ represent the position of the point $p$ when that predefined movement is set to 100%. To make an example, the term $S_{2p1y}$ represent the y position of the point 1 when the predefined movement S2 is 100%.
All the terms "w" are the values I want to find, w stands for weight, and should be a value between 0 and 1(from 0% to 100%). The column vector P is the known terms and represent the position of a point in space in a specified frame.

Basically, I want to decompose the values P in the weights of the predefined movements to know per each frame how much each movement should be activated. Solving the system should be the easy part, what I am bit afraid of is to always get results between 0 and 1. Since it is a linear system there should be only 1 set of solutions, so there is no much I can do, right? I did some digging about the particular application case where I am going to use this system and most common approaches are singular value decomposition and principal component analysys, still I don't see how those might help me to keep the weights between 0 and 1. Do you maybe have any other idea of how I can approach this?

Just to give a bit more context, the "predefined movements" are facial expressions recorded during the calibration of the system, the points being tracked are the motion capture data of the face.

Thanks in advance to everyone.

EDIT: As I was asked I will explain a bit better why I need the weights to be between 0 and 1. Assume that the shape 1 is the movement of the eyebrow lowerer muscle. It can't be negative, it can't go any further than its limit(100%). This applies to all of the shapes.

Comment: I was told that it was not the right place where to post, so I posted it here. I can delete the other one.

Comment: You have a $3m\times n$ matrix, which is presumably taller than it is wide. In that case, this is a bound-constrained linear least-squares problem: minimize $\|{\bf Sw}-{\bf p}\|^2$ subject to $0\le{\bf w}\le1$. Matlab has a function [`lsqlin`](https://in.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/lsqlin.html) that can solve this; presumably Scipy has something similar. *Edit:* Indeed, see [`scipy.optimize.lsq_linear`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.lsq_linear.html).

Comment: @rodrigodeAzevedo yes, I deleted the one on SO.

Comment: @rahul Thanks! I am definitely going to look at it. Do you also have some useful links I can use to understand the math behind it?

Comment: @rodrigodeAzevedo you accidentely deleted some stuff during your edit

Comment: I don't see a particular reason why the weight should be constrained in the range that you describe. Can you elaborate on that? A negative weight would indicate that the measurement is false. As @Rahul proposed you can use a constrained optimization. Another very common approach is to use Tikhonov regularization/ridge regression/weight decay. It helps to penalize large weights as regression coefficients. You could play around with the Tikhonov Matrix to get better results.

Comment: @MrYouMath sure, I added an EDIT to the question